# Why is there no natural isomorphism between $V$ and its dual?

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

### Question

While looking over the exercise $3.F-34$ in *Linear Algebra Done Right*, I encountered the following paragraph

> Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Then $V$ and $V'$ are isomorphic, but finding an isomorphism from $V$ onto $V'$, generally, requires choosing a basis of $V$. In contrast, the isomorphism from $V$ to $V''$ does not require a choice of basis and thus is considered more *natural*.

and these questions showed up in my mind:

$1$. Does the word *natural* just means that we don't need to choose a basis? I have seen the word *canonical* is used in the similar manner too. Is there a more precise definition for *natural* or *canonical*?

$2$. Assuming the answer to question $1$ is *Yes*, then why there is no *natural* isomorphism from $V$ onto $V'$?

$3$. I think that there is a relation between the answer to question $2$ and the proof of Riesz representation theorem. So, if we cannot find a *natural* isomorphism between $V$ and $V'$ then it means that we cannot prove Riesz representation theorem without choosing a basis of $V$. Is this true?

---

### Complementary Information

**The Isomorphism from** $V$ **onto** $V^{''}$.
Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Consider the following map
$$
\Lambda(v)(\phi)=\phi(v),  \qquad \forall v \in V, \,\, \forall \phi \in V^{'}
$$
then $\Lambda$ is an isomorphism from $V$ onto $V''$.

**Riesz Representation Theorem**.
Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional linear space equipped with an inner product and $\phi$ is a linear functional on $V$. Then there is a unique vector $v_0 \in V$ such that
$$\phi(v) = {\langle v,v_0 \rangle}_{V}, \qquad \forall v \in V$$

---

### Other Related Posts

I found the following posts related to this question on MSE and MO.

[Post $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105490/isomorphisms-between-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-and-its-dual), [Post $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188088/isomorphism-with-dual-space), [Post $3$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical), [Post $4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589237/existence-theorem-about-the-adjoint).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105490/isomorphisms-between-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-and-its-dual) for a related question (and answer)

Comment: The Riesz representation theorem gives a natural isomorphism between a finite-dimensional $\textit{inner product space}$ and its dual. I don't think it's a stretch to say that this is THE distinguishing factor between inner product spaces and arbitrary vector spaces. It is taken advantage of endlessly in, say, Hilbert space theory.

Comment: @NoahOlander: So do we have a basis free proof for the Reisz representation theorem I mentioned in the question? If *Yes*, would you please provide a link or reference? :)

Comment: The usual proof depends on finite dimensionality, that is, the existence of a basis. However, it does not require a $\textit{choice}$ of basis. This is more like how you should think of naturality. Also, the definition of the isomorphism is just $v \mapsto \langle _ , v \rangle$, and this definition is intrinsic - no choice of basis necessary. However, to even $\textit{define}$ an isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ for a general vector space, you need to start by choosing a basis.

Comment: @NoahOlander: $v \mapsto \langle _ , v \rangle$ is not an isomorphism because it does not have the homogeneity property! Usually they call it anti-isomorphism, I think. :) (I am assuming that the definition of isomorphism is an invertible **linear** map).

Comment: Haha, I think it's more standard in mathematics (as opposed to physics) to make an inner product linear with respect to the first variable and conjugate linear with respect to the second, but by your book's convention, yes, it should be $v \mapsto \langle v, \underline{ } \rangle$.

Comment: It really is *[Riesz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frigyes_Riesz)*, not *Reisz* (as it is *[Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)*, not *Reimann*).

Comment: @k.stm: Thanks, for clarifying. :)

Comment: @NoahOlander: I am exactly assuming the usual convention in math that you said, i.e., linearity with respect to first variable. :) I think you mixed up the conventions or notations. :)

Comment: You're totally right! Sorry, don't know what I was thinking!

Comment: @NoahOlander: No Problem! :) This happens a lot to me! :D

Comment: We don't need a basis to prove the Riesz theorem. Part of the assumptions in the Riesz theorem is the inner product, and thus the spaces it applies to have more structure than just a plain vector space. This additional structure gives you a "natural" (in the sense that one doesn't need a basis) isomorphism (or anti-isomorphism, in case of complex inner product spaces; if the space has a natural conjugation - as e.g. spaces of complex-valued functions often have - then composing this with the Riesz map gives a natural isomorphism for such complex inner product spaces).

Comment: But if you have only an abstract finite-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field, you don't have enough structure to define a nontrivial natural map $V \to V'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interpretation of natural within category theory that allows us to rigorously state that while there is a *natural* isomorphism from $V$ to $V''$, there is no natural isomorphism between $V$ and $V'$.  This interpretation is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Double_dual_of_a_vector_space) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Unnatural_isomorphism).  The second bit is a little too elaborate for me to wrap my head around, but I'll explain what it is about the $V \to V''$ map which is "natural".

Let $\mathcal C$ denote the category whose objects are finite dimensional vector spaces.  The *morphisms* of this category are the linear maps between vector spaces.  We define a *functor* $F:\mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ by $F(V) = V''$ and $F([V \overset{f}{\to}W]) = [V'' \overset{f''}{\to}W'']$.  What makes this a functor is that for any $f:V \to W$ and $g:U \to V$, we have
$$
F(f \circ g) = F(f) \circ F(g)
$$
We define the much simpler *identity functor* by
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\id(V) = V; \qquad \id([V \overset{f}{\to}W]) = V \overset{f}{\to}W
$$
When we say that $V$ is *naturally isomorphic* to $V''$, we mean that there is a *natural isomorphism* between the functors $\id$ and $F$.  In this case, what this means is that we can assign an isomorphism (invertible morphism) $\eta_V:\id(V) \to F(V)$ to every vector space $V$ in such a way that:

> For every $f:V \to W$, we have $\eta_W \circ \id(f) = F(f) \circ \eta_V$

Or, as we can rephrase it in this context (noting $\id$ is just the identity), we need an $\eta_V:V \to V''$ for every $V$ such that

> for any $f:V \to W$, $\eta_W \circ f \circ \eta_V^{-1} = f''$

Now, what is this $\eta_X$?  Well, it suffices to take
$$
\eta_V:V \to V''\\
[\eta(x)](\alpha) = \alpha(x)
$$
You know that this map is an isomorphism from the text.  Now, we note that for any $\beta \in V''$, there is an $x_\beta$ for which $\alpha(x_{\beta}) = \beta(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha \in V'$, and we have $\eta^{-1}(\beta) = x_{\beta}$.  With that in mind, we can see that for any $f:V \to W$ and for any $\beta \in V''$ and $\alpha \in V'$, we have

$$\begin{align}
[[\eta_W\circ f \circ \eta_V^{-1}](\beta)](\alpha) &=
[[\eta_W\circ f](x_{\beta})](\alpha) \\
&= [\eta_W(f(x_{\beta}))](\alpha) \\
&= \alpha(f(x_{\beta})) \\
&= [\alpha \circ f](x_{\beta}) \\
&= \beta (\alpha \circ f) \\
&= \beta (f'(\alpha)) \\
&= [\beta \circ f'](\alpha) \\
&= [f'' (\beta)](\alpha)
\end{align}$$
as required.